# NullPointerException unstoppable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, vaadin

I am currently working on a small addresstable with vaadin, just to get to know vaadin a little. I have run into a problem, where I want to sort the entries of my table manually. The problem is, that I get a NullPointerException when i try to do this:

```
item.getItemProperty(Columns.NAME).getValue()
```

I have tried a few things here. I checked item and item isn't null, neither is item.getItemProperty(Columns.NAME) null. So when I try to make an if I still get a NullPointerException

```
if(item.getItemProperty(Columns.NAME).getValue() == null){}
```

The value is null and I understand that, but I want to give this value to an other item and I have no idea how to.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.example.addresstable.AddresstableUI$Servlet] in context with path [/Addresstable] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer$IndexedContainerProperty.getValue(IndexedContainer.java:898)
  at com.example.addresstable.AddressTable.addAddressToTable(AddressTable.java:114)
  at com.example.addresstable.AddresstableUI.init(AddresstableUI.java:26)
  at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:639)
  at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
  at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
  at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
  at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1402)
  at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `item.getItemProperty(Columns.NAME)` returns null?

Comment: Look through the stacktrace of the exception to see where it is coming from

Comment: what if not `item.getItemProperty(Columns.NAME).getValue()`, but `item` itself is `null`? Check the exception stacktrace, as @codebox suggested and try your luck.

Comment: This exception is telling you that `item` or `item.getItemProperty(Columns.NAME)` is `null`. You need to figure out why that is the case.

Comment: can you post StackTrace?

Comment: Without stack trace, based on your comments, getValue must be dereferencing some null value. _For instance:_ `void setValue(X x) { x = x; }` (instead of `this.x = x;`) and then doing `x.toString()` in getValue. **Do:** `if (item == null ||item.getP... == null || item.getP... .getValue() == null)`

Comment: please post your stacktrace so we get some more information. In my opinion item.getItemProperty(Columns.NAME) is null. And from what type is the Item, is the JavaDoc telling something about this NullPointerException?

Comment: item isn't null I think @JoopEggen is right.

Comment: You should post the code at least of AddressTable.java.

Comment: For the interested, line 898 of [IndexedContainer](http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/vaadin/server/src/com/vaadin/data/util/IndexedContainer.java) is `return (T) items.get(itemId).get(propertyId);`

Comment: @JonK has the solution, something in the code of Valedin throws the NullPointerException. -> return (T) items.get(itemId).get(propertyId); Can you see what the itemId and popertyId are?

Comment: @JonK yes thank you it is items.get(itemId) which returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexedContainer`'s `Item`s are `IndexedContainerItem`.
When call it's `getItemProperty` the result is never null:

```
@Override
public Property getItemProperty(Object id) {
    return new IndexedContainerProperty(itemId, id);
}
```

But when you call `Property`'s `getValue` it may be null if there is no itemId or propertyId:

```
@Override
public T getValue() {
    return (T) items.get(itemId).get(propertyId);
}
```

Probably it is a Vaadin bug: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164040/getitemproperty-returns-not-null-vaadin-bug)

**EDIT**

If you want to check the container contains the item, you can do this:

```
public class MyIndexedContainer extends IndexedContainer {
    @Override
    public Item getUnfilteredItem(Object itemId) { // make it public
      return super.getUnfilteredItem(itemId);
    }
}
```

then

```
Table table = new Table();
MyIndexedContainer mic = new MyIndexedContainer();
table.setContainerDataSource(mic);
//...
// check that the container contains the item
if (mic.getUnfilteredItem(item) != null) {
    //...
}
```